# Does water in the water heater drip pan mean my heater is bad?

Tags: water, leak, heater

I recently noticed my drip pan had about a half-inch of water in it. I could find no water leaks around the fittings or valves.

The water is slowly evaporating--very dry climate area--and the water in the pan is almost gone.

The heater works well and we have plenty of hot water, could there be an intermittent leak?

Comment: Do you have an expansion tank (small metal bottle attached to the plumbing near the heater)?  What is the temperature setting on the heater?

Comment: No, there is not an expansion bottle. The temp setting is 130

Comment: Is there a check valve on the main water supply?

Comment: There's an on/off valve on the cold water inlet pipe...that's the only valve I can see

Comment: It won't have a handle on it like a normal valve, or will be a small fitting near the meter with an arrow on it pointing in the direction of flow.

Comment: Not sure about most places, but all the residential water meters I know are at the street, and I would expect that a check valve is required on any municipal system, the chance for excess pressure pushing anything back into the mains is just too dangerous to avoid a check valve.

Comment: The options are condensation or leak. If you did not find anything around the exposed fittings or valves, the source must be somewhere you can not see. If it is electric, the elements are a point of failure, the anode entry point, or where the bottom drain valve connects to the tank are all possible places for a leak that would not be easy to see.

Comment: @SomeGuy In cold climates, it's common for the meter to be in the building's basement, to protect it from freezing.   It's also possible that the installation predates the requirement for a check valve, and it has not yet been updated to include one.

Comment: @Zevkat After you take a shower (or other high demand activity), if you open a hot water tap, do you notice a surge of water before it settles back to a normal flow? Does the discharge tube for the T&P valve drain into the pan, or a drain?

Comment: Removed the insulating blanket and there was a 4 inch split in the seam about halfway up the side on the back of the unit. It was not leaking water though. Had a plumber check it out and he stated that unit had just rusted thru at that point but he could not explain why it only leaked the one time and still worked. Thanks for all the help from the forum

Answer (score 1):

My thermostat stopped working, my electric water heater got too hot, and water boiled out of the T&P valve. I just had to replace the thermostat. Have it looked at by a plumber. 
So yes, this can be an intermittent thing.

And yes, there could be a slow leak somewhere else.

What type of WH is it? Gas, electric? Please add this answer to the bottom of your post.